# Can you help me identify the error in this code? I dont seem to understand why it isn't working?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays

The link to the question I'm having trouble in...

My logic was to start a loop from the end of the array and move forwards, checking which elements are in position, and swapping to get the elements in their right position, I'm attaching my code below. I swap one by one because that's how they showed it in the sample test case.

```
    static void minimumBribes(int[] q) {

    int moves = 0;
    boolean tc = false;

    for(int i = q.length-1; i >= 0; i--){

        if(q[i] != i+1 && q[i] >= (i+1)){

            int diff = q[i] - (i+1);
            if(diff > 2){

                System.out.println("Too chaotic");
                tc = true;
            }else{

                moves = moves + diff;
                for(int j = 1; j <= diff; j++){

                    arrSwap(q, i-1+j, i+j);
                }
                i--;
            }
        }else{

            continue;
        }
    }
    if(tc == false){

        System.out.println(moves);
    }

}

public static void arrSwap (int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;

}
```

Input:
1 2 5 3 4 7 8 6

Output:
3

Expected Output:
4

Comment: Please share your function's unit tests too.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bobble sortting solve this problem.Here is my code:

```
static void minimumBribes(int[] q) {
    int []res=new int[q.length];
    boolean change=true;
    for(int i=0;i<q.length;i++)
        res[i]=0;
    while(change){
        change=false;
        for(int i=0,j=i+1;j<q.length;i++,j++){
            if(q[i]>q[j]){
                res[q[i]-1]++;
                arrSwap(q,i,j);
                change=true;
            }
        }
    }
    int n=0;
    for(int i=0;i<q.length;i++){
        if(res[i]>2){
            System.out.println("Too chaotic");
            return;
        }
        else
            n+=res[i];
    }
    System.out.println(n);
}

public static void arrSwap (int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

My code may be not the best solution.